# Outlook login request showing blank screen?

Tags: java, outlook, google-nativeclient

I am using below API for login to outlook but its showing me blank screen

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient? 
code=M6aff8423-620b-5d13-3d9d-e966554eea&state=x1en-9M1Q1zHoTFod-40Q
```

Previously it was working but suddenly it showing blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling my phone chrome browser !!